# How to make sublime text editor highlight left bar area on active code block

Tags: ide, sublimetext, text-editor, sublimetext3

Sometimes I feal lost while coding on sublime text editor as it doesn't highlight the left bar as others ides/text editors do
what I am talking about is the light violet color on line numbers as in *eclipse*.

[image: eclipse]

But in *Sublime text Editor* its simply an small dash beneath curly braces.

[image: sublime text image]

Is there any way I can get this in *sublime text editor* ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your user, preferences file:

```
"highlight_line": true
```

You can find a great many helpful visual aids by looking in the default preferences file and the copying any over to your user file. Don't change settings in the default file though. Always add them to the user file.

Comment: Apologies. I misunderstood what you wanted. For clearer marks in the line number area I would recommend a plugin like https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter